# Local Storage web database , where is it?

Tags: sql, database, html, local-storage

can i actually see the locally created Sql light databases .?

for example: where does chrome stores them ? (which folder ?)

thanks

Comment: Not an answer but if you just want to peek/edit the data in chrome you can look in F12->Resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it exists, you can see it with "Developers Tools" (press CTRL+SHIFT+I). 
After you've opened it, go to the "Resources tab" and on the left a list of resource used by the site. 
One of them is "Databases", where you can find databases used by the site.